Toast Message on Manual Case Creation using New Button
Whenever I am creating a case in Salesforce manually the toast message is showing the url case id, But I want to show the Case Number.

I have searched and haven't found any without code solution.
Please someone guide how to do this from UI.
If not then how to make changes in code and on which path.

You might not have the case number field on the page layout. You should have the case number field on the page layout to display the number on the toast message. Adding the case number to the page layout should help in this case.

Case Number is added in Layout. And It is working fine in QA and Dev environment but not on UAT.

Verify the page layout assignment for the case object. Ensure that the record type of the record you are trying to create has the correct page layout assigned to the user you are testing with.

Yes, It is correctly assigned and also I am checking with System Admin. Any other suggestion where else I can check on this

Thanks, It is working fine now. Your first point is working.

Glad I could help. You can upvote and mark the answer as accepted so, it will be beneficial for other members who will face similar issues in the future
